# How to format person height in EditText to reflect inches and feet?

Tags: android, format, android-edittext

I have an EditText field in my app which is for person's height. How do I format it to make it look like say 5'9"? When a person types 5 the app should add ' by itself and when a person types 9 it should add ". How do I do that? Thank you.

Comment: try to implement [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
public class TextWatcherActivity extends Activity {

    EditText e;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        e.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(e));
    }
}

class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText mEditText;

    public CustomTextWatcher(EditText e) {
        mEditText = e;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int count = s.length();
        String str = s.toString();
        if (count == 1) {
            str = str + "'";
        } else if (count == 2) {
            return;
        } else if (count == 3) {
            str = str + "\"";
        } else if (count >= 4) {
            return;
        }
        mEditText.setText(str);
            mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText().length());
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

If user can insert one,two and more digit between `'` and `"` change `afterTextChanged` in above code like this:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    int count = s.length();
    String str = s.toString();
    if (count == 1) {
        str = str + "'";
    } else if (count == 3) {
        str = str + "\"";
    } else if ((count > 4) && (str.charAt(str.length() - 1) != '\"') ){
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 2) + str.charAt(str.length() - 1)
        + "\"";
    } else {
        return;
    }
    mEditText.setText(str);
    mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText().length());
}
```

Comment: Thank you hasanghaforian. It is working fine except one issue. It doesn't work if I type 5'11". If the second number is two digits it doens't work properly. But thank you anyway.

Comment: No, if a person's height is 5'9" than he types only one digit in between ' and "

Comment: I am going to add another if statement to check the string character at position 2 and if it is equals 1 than the " sign won't be added. Is it a good idea?

Comment: Yes it is working fine. Thank you for your help Hasanghaforian!

Comment: @SeanKilb Please add check mark to answer,if it is true.So it will be marked as `accepted answer`.

Comment: there is one problem, if i try to delete the text from edit text only numbers get deleted not ' and " from edit text.

Comment: on removing text it is not working nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

use this : 
for delete "'".

```
mBinding.edtHeight.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                if (mBinding.edtHeight.getText().length() == 2) {
                    mBinding.edtHeight.setText("");
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```